# NSXMLParser Failed to parse data on watch but working fine on watch simulator

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch, watch, watchos-2

**NSXMLParser** Failed to parse data on **watch** but working fine on **watch simulator**.How to resolve this issue?

Kindly help

Here is Code:

```
    let url:String="http://www.someurl.com/data"
    let urlToSend: NSURL = NSURL(string: url)!
    // Parse the XML
    parser = NSXMLParser(contentsOfURL: urlToSend)!
    parser.delegate = self

    let success:Bool = parser.parse()

    if success {
        print("parse success!")

        print(strXMLData)


    } else {
        print("parse failure!")
    }
```

Comment: Code is pasted.This Code fetching data fine on watch simulator.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced the same issue, and I couldn't debug the app when running on the watch. My solution was to parse the XML file in the iPhone App side and communicate the data to the watch through a WCSession.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem. I found an answer on one of Apple's own forums.

You need to read in the XML from URL into NSData, then invoke XML parser with NSData object, not the NSURL.

Here is some code

```
var nsXMLData = NSData()
var parser = NSXMLParser()

func xmlFileRequest(urlweb:NSURL){

    print("in xmlFileRequest")

    let requestURL: NSURL = urlweb
    let urlRequest: NSMutableURLRequest = 
         NSMutableURLRequest(URL: requestURL)
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(urlRequest) {
        (data, response, error) -> Void in

        if error == nil {
            print(">>>>>>xmlFileRequest success!")
            self.nsXMLData = data!
            self.beginParsing()
        } else {
            print(">>>>>>>xmlFileRequest fail")
        }

    }
    task.resume()
}

func beginParsing()
{
    parser = NSXMLParser.init(data:nsXMLData)

    parser.delegate = self
    let success:Bool = parser.parse()
    if success {
        print("***parse success***")

    } else {
        print("***parse failure!***")
        let errorMsg:String =
            (parser.parserError?.localizedDescription)!
        print("Error = " + errorMsg)
    }

}
```

I just tested this code on our Apple watch.